# Next JS 12 Giving 404 Error for Invalid Static Route JSON File

Tags: reactjs, next.js, newrelic

I have a website using NextJS 12.3.1. Website is SSG and hosted on a server. When Navigating Between Statically Generated Pages using Static Routes. I see this Error in Console and Network Tab with 404 Error. It tries to fetch the URL `/_next/data/q1YJR6lidq9x7sroWHl-4/news/%5Bpid%5D.json?pid=%5Bpid%5D` From the Server, but as it's an invalid file with `[pid].json` name, Server returns 404 Error.

Similarly requests to `/_next/data/q1YJR6lidq9x7sroWHl-4/news/undefined.json?pid=undefined` files can be seen.

This happens when reloading or opening the page and Navigating programetically using the  component.

```
 <Link href={`/news/${uri}`}>
                <a className="button">Read</a>
 </Link>
```

Cleared Cache in Server, but seeing the error.

Comment: It looks like your `uri` variable is undefined. I would look at where you declare this variable, and make sure it's valid.

Comment: I found out it's caused by newrelic.js monitoring Snippet. It's working but giving this kind of issues for Next JS statically generated pages.